# How to select the max date from table in c# linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am stack here I need someone help please. I want to get the maximum date from different table where Refno equal Refno.
My current code is giving me all date that exist in the actionrecords table.

**My Current code look like**

```
public IQueryable<EmployerDetails> _employerProfileOverview(string refNo, string organisationname, string tradingname)
{
    var query = (from _employerdetails in _entities.Organisations
                 join _lasttransaction in _entities.LevyTransactions on _employerdetails.Refno equals _lasttransaction.Refno
                 select new EmployerDetails
                 {
                     RefNo = _employerdetails.Refno,
                     Surname = _employerdetails.Surname,
                     TradingName = _employerdetails.TradingName,
                     Status = _employerdetails.Status,
                     TransactionDate = _lasttransaction.TransactionDate
                 });
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(refNo).Equals(false))
        query = query.Where(x => x.RefNo.Contains(refNo.Trim()));

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(organisationname).Equals(false))
        query = query.Where(x => x.Surname.Contains(organisationname.Trim()));

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tradingname).Equals(false))
        query = query.Where(x => x.TradingName.Contains(tradingname.Trim()));

    return query;
}
```

**And my out put look like this**

```
 Refno      TradingName                  Status  TransactionDate
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2011-01-01 00:00:00.000
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2012-03-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2012-04-01 00:00:00.000
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2012-05-01 00:00:00.000
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2012-06-01 00:00:00.000
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2012-07-01 00:00:00.000
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2012-08-01 00:00:00.000
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2012-09-01 00:00:00.000
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2012-10-01 00:00:00.000
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2012-11-01 00:00:00.000
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2012-12-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2013-02-01 00:00:00.000
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2013-03-01 00:00:00.000
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2013-04-01 00:00:00.000
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2013-05-01 00:00:00.000
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2013-06-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2013-11-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2013-12-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2014-02-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2014-03-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2014-04-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2014-05-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2014-06-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2014-07-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2014-08-01 00:00:00.00  
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2014-09-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2014-10-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2014-11-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2014-12-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2015-03-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2015-04-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2015-05-01 00:00:00.000 
L940732953  PSG KONSULT BPK LICHTENBURG     A   2015-06-01 00:00:00.000 
L940733035  BROUGHTON AND JONCK             A   2011-05-01 00:00:00.000 
L940733035  BROUGHTON AND JONCK             A   2011-05-01 00:00:00.000 
L940733035  BROUGHTON AND JONCK             A   2011-05-01 00:00:00.000 
L940733035  BROUGHTON AND JONCK             A   2011-05-01 00:00:00.000 
L940733035  BROUGHTON AND JONCK             A   2011-05-01 00:00:00.000 
L940733035  BROUGHTON AND JONCK             A   2011-05-01 00:00:00.000 
L940736574  COVERS FOODS CC                 Y   2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 
L940736574  COVERS FOODS CC                 Y   2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 
L940736574  COVERS FOODS CC                 Y   2011-05-01 00:00:00.000 
L940736574  COVERS FOODS CC                 Y   2011-05-01 00:00:00.000 
L940738141  TEAMWORX SHOPFITTERS (PTY) LTD  A   2011-01-01 00:00:00.000
L940738141  TEAMWORX SHOPFITTERS (PTY) LTD  A   2011-02-01 00:00:00.000
L940738141  TEAMWORX SHOPFITTERS (PTY) LTD  A   2011-02-01 00:00:00.000
L940738141  TEAMWORX SHOPFITTERS (PTY) LTD  A   2011-04-01 00:00:00.000
L940738141  TEAMWORX SHOPFITTERS (PTY) LTD  A   2011-05-01 00:00:00.000
```

I just want to display max(Transaction) only each an every Refno.

Please help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `group by` here and use the [Max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347632(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method to find maximum transaction date:-

```
 var query = (from _employerdetails in _entities.Organisations
              join _lasttransaction in _entities.LevyTransactions 
              on _employerdetails.Refno equals _lasttransaction.Refno
              group new { _employerdetails, _lasttransaction } 
              by new { _employerdetails.Refno, 
                       _employerdetails.Surname_employerdetails.TradingName, 
                       _employerdetails.Status } into g
              select new EmployerDetails
              {
                  RefNo = g.Key.RefNo ,
                  Surname = g.Key.Surname,
                  TradingName = g.Key.TradingName,
                  Status = g.Key.Status,
                  TransactionDate = g.Max(x => x._lasttransaction .TransactionDate)
              });
```

Also, as a side note since [String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) returns boolean, no need to compare it with `false` or `true`. You can directly do this:-

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(refNo))
        query = query.Where(x => x.RefNo.Contains(refNo.Trim()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line just before the return statement:

```
query = query.OrderByDescending(q => q.TransactionDate).First();
```

Another option is to use the Max by property function in [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) which will make the code more elegant.

Also, you should write:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(refNo))
```